# Regex to extract nth token of a string separated by pipes

Tags: regex, db2, db2-400

I'm new in Regex

I need to count and extract tokens from the below sample text:

```
AA||CCCCCCCC|||FFFFFFFFFFF
```

Requesting 4th token I must get a empty '' string, requesting 6th I must get 'FFFFFFFFFFF'

Would it be possible to have such regex?

Thanks in Advance!

*PS: For token counting I've used `'\|'` adding +1 to the result is the string is not empty, surely there another more efficient way to do that using just a regex...*

Comment: Just explode/split on the `|` in your programming language, that would be  be a lot easier.

Comment: What OS/RDBMS/program or editor are you working in?  Not all versions of regular expressions are created equal.  Please update the tags to show.

Comment: I will use DB2 **REGEXP_COUNT** and **REGEXP_SUBSTR** scalar functions.

Comment: The extra mile: Is is possible to obtain the first token having a  specific value? 'CCCCCCCC' -> 3 , 'FFFFFFFFFFF' -> 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DB2 please try this to get the 6th element in the list.  This works on Oracle and allows for NULL list elements.  The syntax for the REGEXP_SUBSTR call is the same so I suspect it will work:

```
regexp_substr('AA||CCCCCCCC|||FFFFFFFFFFF', '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 6, 'c', 1)
```

EDIT: 'c' for case-sensitive

Answer (score 6):

Splitting the string on `|` would be more effective, but this works too.

### Code

We'll call the counter the number between curly brackets `{X}`. That counter begins at 0. If it's set to `0`, we'll get the `1st` element, if it's set to `5`, we'll get the `6th` element, etc.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/BQs2rt/1)

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){5}\K[^|]*
```

Alternatively, if `\K` isn't supported in your regex engine, you can use the following (result in the first capture group):

```
^(?:[^|]*\|){5}([^|]*)
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?:[^|]*\|){5}` Match the following exactly 5 times

  - `[^|]*` Match any character except `|` any number of times
  - `\|` Match `|` literally
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `[^|]*` Match any character except `|` any number of times

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!